# Calling shapefiles stored in ArcGIS Server to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I am kind of new to ArcGIS Web application development. I have very limited credits for my ArcGIS Online account. Therefore I am trying to host GIS layers in the ArcGIS Server and load it into ArcGIS Online via an **ArcGIS Server Web Service** .
I have tried adding the following layer using the URL mentioned in the image.

[image: Image of the ArcGIS Server layer]

In ArcGIS online account, I used the **Add Layer from Web** option to load that particular layer into the ArcGIS online account.

[image]

Once I added the Administrative boundaries layers, It shows in the Map.
[image]

However, when share the map application, the users (Outside the local network) cannot see the particular layer and It gives the following error window. [This is the link for the Webmap](https://arcg.is/1j0T9K1)
[image]

Comment: Have you installed the web adapter? ArcGIS Server isn't supposed to be connected to the outside world, the web adapter in your 'orange zone' is intended to link the outside with the inside.

Comment: This is the first time I am configuring ArcGIS Server for Web Application Development. Could you point out briefly on how to install Web adapter?

Comment: Error messages should always be included as text in the body of the Question (images are not legible on all devices and are not searchable by others with the same error). The part you have scribbled out in your AGOL reference is the important part, that others need to be able to access (if it's firewalled or otherwise inaccessible, then you can't use it to publish data to others).

Comment: You will need to install the Web Adaptor on a web server and configure DNS. This will make an 'externally' facing url without the port number (ex. https://webadaptorhost.domain.com/webadaptorname/rest/services) . Then users outside your org can access the rest service directly or through your AGO map. https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/about-the-arcgis-web-adaptor.htm

Comment: @Tigerwoulds I have configured the webadaptor as well. However, when I tried to access the services directory of `GISSERVER.INT` I get the  
`Cannot proxy HTTP request, ArcGIS Server has been configured to accept only HTTPS requests. Please configure your Web Server to use SSL/HTTPS.` message.

Comment: IMO You shouldn't be allowing HTTP, the S in HTTPS means secure, you can never be too safe online with your data. If you insist on the unsafe there is a web page admin for the web adapter that routes on the different ports: HTTP is port 80, HTTPS uses port 443. Internally your ArcGIS Server uses ports 6080 for HTTP and 6443 for HTTPS, all Web Adapter does is route port 6080=>80 and 6443=>443 **specifically**, you will need to assert your internal port to 6080 and external port to 80 if you want to go with unsafe HTTP or assert the safe ports and use HTTPS, exactly as the error message states.